# Given coordinates $(p, p^2), (r, r^2),$ and $(q, q^2)$ in a right triangle, find $p - r$.

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

**Question:** Right-angled $\triangle PQR$ with $\angle{PQR} = 90°$ is inscribed in the parabola with equation $y = x^2$. Points $P, Q$,
and $R$ have coordinates $(p, p^2), (q, q^2)$ and $(r, r^2)$, respectively. If $p, q,$ and $r$ are all integers, what is the
largest possible absolute value of the difference $p - r$?

**My solution:** We must first realize that $QR \perp QP$. This means that the slope of $QR$ times the slope of $QP$ is $-1$.

So, calculating the slope of $QR$ and $QP$, we get that the slope of $QR = \frac{q^2 - r^2}{q - r} = \frac{(q - r)(q + r)}{q - r}$ and since points $P, Q$, and $R$ are distinct, $q \neq r$. So, the $q - r$ on both the numerator and denominator cancel out and gives that the slope of $QR = q + r$.

Similarly, the slope of $QP = q + p$.

Hence, $(q + r)(q + p) = -1$. But, the problem states that $p, q,$ and $r$ are integers. So, the only possible ways for this to occur is if $q + r = 1$ and $q + p = -1$ or $q + r = -1$ and $q + p = 1$. Subtracting both equations in each scenario, we get $p - r = 2, -2$.

Hence, the absolute value of $p - r$ is equal to $\boxed{2}$.

Please check over my solution for mistakes and inaccuracies to see if I got my solution wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks OK to me.

Comment: @Andrei thanks!

Comment: Bonus question: find $p$, $q$, $r$

Comment: @Andrei is that even possible?

Comment: Not sure. But it would be interesting to find out

Comment: @Andrei I don't think that it is possible due to the limited amount of information, but maybe!

Comment: There are multiple coordinates that would work, examples - $P(3, 9), Q(-2, 4), R(1, 1)$ or $P(5,25), Q (-4, 16), R (3, 9)$...

Comment: @MathLover yes exactly.